# Grails If-else condition for radio buttons

Tags: if-statement, radio-button, grails-2.0

I have 3 radio buttons which when selected, will run different query.
I have no idea how the if-else condition works for grails radio buttons as I'm completely new to grails..
this is my gsp page.

```
<label>Search id:</label><input type = "text" name = "searchid1">
<input type ="submit" name ="search" value ="Go!">

<br>

<g:radio name="myGroup" value="input1"/>

<g:radio name="myGroup" value="input2"/>

<g:radio name="myGroup" value="input3"/>
```

and the queries at the controller site..

```
String searchQ1 = "select * from alert_list where id = " + params.searchid1
def searchit1 = sql.rows(searchQ1)

String searchQ2 = "select * from Admin where id = " + params.searchid1
def searchit2 = sql.rows(searchQ2)

String searchQ3 = "select * from sec_user where id = " + params.searchid1
def searchit3 = sql.rows(searchQ3)

[searchit1: searchit1, searchit2: searchit2, searchit3: searchit3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method you're using for GSP is correct. However, in the controller you need to add in IF-ELSE statement.

```
if (request.getParameter("myGroup").equals("input1"))
        {

        println("duck")
        redirect (action: radio)

        }

        if (request.getParameter("myGroup").equals("input2"))
        {
            println("chicken")
            redirect (action: abc)

        }
```

Add the if-else condition in your controller and your problem will be fixed.